# JS Update Map element in Dynamo table

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

**TL/DR:** How do I update a single Map key/value without modifying the whole Map in Dynamo?

I have a Map inside a simple table. Im trying to implement an UPDATE, but I'm unsure how to reference the key/value pair of the Map object. Here is what I tried, along with a screenshot of my table:

[image]

passing in the params updq(updated question),updans (updated answer),ans(original answer),qq (original question)

```
var params = {
  TableName: TABLE_NAME,
  Key: { topic: topic },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#qq": qq,
    "#updq": updq,
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":ans": ans,
    ":updans": updans,
  },
};
if (!doUpdate) {
  //replace/create
  params["UpdateExpression"] = "SET questions.#qq = :ans"; //this works
} else {
    params["UpdateExpression"] = "SET questions.#updq = :updq, _____"; //<<<<<<<<<<THIS DOESNT
}

console.log(`writing params: `, params);
let res = await docClient.update(params).promise();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a new question:
questions map already exists, so, `SET questions.#qq = :ans` will create an entry into MAP

```
  params.ExpressionAttributeNames = {
    "#qq": qq,
  };
  params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
    ":ans": ans,
  };
  params.UpdateExpression = "SET questions.#qq = :ans";
```

For updating an existing, could be question itself not just the answer, So, we need to drop the existing question and create a new one, so, we need to add `REMOVE questions.#qq`

```
  params.ExpressionAttributeNames = {
    "#qq": qq,
    "#updq": updq,
  };
  params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
    ":updans": updans,
  };
  params.UpdateExpression =
    "REMOVE questions.#qq SET questions.#updq = :updans";
}
```